# AIX 6.1 -- Without root can I get the last failed login for a user i have access to?

Tags: security, logs, login, aix

I know the information is in the security files but I don't have access and it's more work then I want to do to go to our Unix admins to get the information (everytime the account gets locked which is often)

If I have access to user A but not to root is there a way to get unsuccessful login information?

Comment: I don't have definitive information, but I'd be surprised if unsuccessful logins were recorded anywhere public. Normally this information is for system administrators only. You probably need to be in the `adm` group if not root.

Answer (score 1):

The last unsuccessful login attempt is shown upon successful login to the system for that particular user, above the last login and the MOTD (if the latter exists). That is, if this is not [suppressed by the existence of an empty file `~/.hushlogin`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/suppress_login_msgs.htm?lang=en)

The failed logins are stored in /etc/security/lastlog, which is only accessible to root, and readable by the group security (where by default root is the only member).
[More details on the stored attributes in lastlog](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/lastlog.htm)

Failed logins are also stored in [/etc/security/failedlogins which has the same format as wtmp](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/utmp.htm), permissions are the same as above.

Regular users can only use e.g. `last` or `lastlog` to show last successful logins for other users.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure but you could try the commands `lastlog`, `last` or `faillog`. These are commands on Linux but *might* be available to you on AIX.

#### Examples

*last*

```
$ last root
root     tty2                          Mon Sep 16 08:05 - down   (00:00)    
root     tty2                          Sat Aug 31 13:21 - down   (00:02)    
root     tty3                          Sat Aug 31 13:20 - down   (00:02)    
root     pts/19       greeneggs.bubba. Wed Aug 21 01:54 - 03:10  (01:15)    
root     pts/19       greeneggs.bubba. Wed Aug 21 01:49 - 01:49  (00:00)    
root     pts/19       greeneggs.bubba. Wed Aug 21 01:47 - 01:47  (00:00)    
root     pts/19       greeneggs.bubba. Wed Aug 21 01:40 - 01:40  (00:00)    
root     pts/19       greeneggs.bubba. Wed Aug 21 01:27 - 01:31  (00:03)    
root     pts/18       localhost.locald Tue Aug 20 22:51 - 22:51  (00:00)    
root     pts/7        localhost.locald Tue Aug 20 11:27 - 11:50  (00:23)    
root     tty2                          Thu Aug  1 17:53 - 17:54  (00:00)    
root     tty2                          Thu Jul 25 15:19 - down   (00:03)    
root     tty2                          Sun Jun 30 02:27 - 14:29 (9+12:02)   
root     tty2                          Mon May 27 10:32 - down   (00:01)
```

*lastlog*

```
$ lastlog -u root
Username         Port     From             Latest
root             tty2                      Mon Sep 16 08:05:29 -0400 2013
```

*faillog*

Newer systems also include a command `faillog` which might show what you want after.

#### Wrap up

Again these are the tools on a Linux box but they might be available to you as well on AIX!

Comment: No luck... only thing available to be is `last` and that doesnt show failed attempts. Thanks for the lead though.

Comment: You can look up AIX man pages online: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp